# Binomial Expansion to Evaluate the Value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3.4}}$

Tags: binomial-theorem

I've found the binomial expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}$ to be
$1-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{8}x^2-\frac{5}{16}x^3+...$, but why does the series converge for $x=2.4$? Is it because $x>1$?

So how can I otherwise evaluate the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3.4}}$ using the binomial expansion?

Comment: Well... obviously the series converge since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2.4}}$ exists. The series, however, do not converge for $-1\geq x$...

Comment: Ok... But why doesn't the series seem to converge when I calculate and add up the first few terms?

Comment: In fact to say that the series converge is misleading. Each additional term is bigger than the previous, so there is no convergence... This is no true convergence. The binomial expression is supposed to be reserved for very small $x$, where the terms are getting smaller and smaller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3.4}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-0.6}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-0.15}}$$ I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{4+x}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{x}{4}}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{x}{4}\right)^{-1/2}$, so now

you can
substitute $\frac{x}{4}$ for $x$ in your series, and then replace $x$ by -.6.